# Qt QNetworkAccessManager or other method get html status code without getting page contenet?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

i need to get web sites html status codes 
today i just do simple get request to the domain , and then i get the status code as part of the response , but also the site index.html content .

```
pNetworkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
reply = pNetworkManager->get(request);
QVariant vStatusCodeV =  reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    QVariant redirectionTarget = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);


data=reply->readAll();
```

this last function i like to avoid if it can be avoided , 
is there any way to get only the domain status code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @shevron's answer, but if the site you're communicating with isn't "clever" enough to implement the `HEAD` request, you can still avoid the `readAll()` call.

```
QByteArray line = reply->readLine();  //< eg "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
QList<QByteArray> chunks = line.split(' ');
QString statusCode = chunks[1];
```

That should avoid the memory overhead of `readAll()`.

Comment: what is the difference between head and reading first line ? 
why does site must to implement using head request ?

Comment: @user63898 The header is simply the first part of the reply contents. The only way to differentiate the headers from the data, according to the HTTP spec, is to look for `\n\r\n\r`. The first line of the response will contain a line similar to `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`, so my example takes advantage of that by reading only the first line and not the entire contents into memory. Most popular web servers (apache/nginx/etc) should implement the `HEAD` request, but if you're talking to a site with a custom HTTP server, it may not support `HEAD` (even though it's supposed to).

Comment: what about this? reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
is this as the same readline ?

Comment: @user63898 Looks reasonable, I hadn't thought of that. Good find.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can send a HEAD request instead of a GET request?

This is not a Qt / client specific solution, but is the approach recommended by the HTTP protocol when you don't need the content, but just want to get the headers that a request would normally produce, for example in order to validate that the page exists.

I suppose this could be done with QNetworkAccessManager using the [head() method](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#head)